# triple monitor set up ubuntu 16

Tags: display, display-resolution, display-manager

Wondering if you can connect 2 monitors to the laptop.
The 2 monitors have the same resolution (1920x1080) one is HDMI (**HDMI1**) and the other is VGA (**VGA1**). The laptop has 1366x768 and it's called **LVDS1**

I get this errors:

```
could not set the configuration for CRTC 96
```

And

```
GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._gsd_2drr_2derror_2dquark.Code2: could not set the configuration for CRTC 96
```

If I use arandr I get this error

```
XRandR returned error code 1: xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
```

**UPDATE**

I have researched on the Intenet and I have found this instruction:

```
xrandr --fb 1920x1080 --output LVDS1 --mode 1366x768 --scale-from 1920x1080 --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1080 --scale 1x1 --same-as LVDS1 --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --scale 1x1 --same-as LVDS1
```

Now I can see the same on the three monitors. I don't want to duplicate but extend.
For This, I Have used **arandr** but I can only extend one monitor. I can't separate the HDMI and the VGA.

Has anyone a solution? 
Thank you!